# Flask + Heroku: H12 Request Timeout Error

Tags: javascript, flask, heroku

I have a Heroku app to run Scrapy Spider. After starting, I get error H12. How to fix it?

JQuery:

```js
$.post('/wellness', {'specialty': specialty, 'state': state, 'city': city}, (res) => { 
      $(location).attr('href', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/wellness')
    });
```

flask:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    specialty = request.form.getlist('specialty[]')
    state = request.form.getlist('state[]')
    city = request.form.getlist('city[]')

    settings = ''
    with open(file_json, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.read():
            settings += line

    settings = json.loads(settings)
    settings['specialty'] = specialty
    settings['state'] = state
    settings['city'] = city

    with open(file_json, 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(settings, indent=4))

    process = subprocess.Popen('python spiders/' + file_py, shell=True)
    process.wait()

return render_template(file_html)
```

Comment: Does your app deployed successfully on heroku?

Comment: Yes, but there is no response from the server, since the spider has been collecting data for a long time

Comment: Error code H12 indicates the app took over 30 seconds to respond to the Heroku router. you can check here: https://blog.papertrailapp.com/analyzing-heroku-router-logs-with-papertrail/#:~:text=Error%20code%20H12%20indicates%20the,Timeout%20in%20the%20Heroku%20DevCenter.